# What is the difference between add 'text' property or directly use within tags?

Tags: asp.net

for example :

what is the exact difference between following statements:

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server">hi</asp:TextBox>
```

and

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" text="HI"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is Simply **No Difference**.

You can change the text of both texboxes from code behind using `textbox1.text = "something"`.